# Graphics.clearRect() won't work for me

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

Hi I've searched the web for a while but the solves I've encountered don't work for me. So here's my issue:

I'm making some graphs on my GUI by using Graphics and drawLine(), which works perfectly fine for me - the first time. When I tell my program to redraw another graph on the same area it just messes things up.

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int max = 100;
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 205, 200); <-- 

        g.drawRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
        g.drawString(""+max, 0, 10);
        g.drawLine(5, 110, 10, 110);
        g.drawString("0", 0, 275);

        ...Drawing the actual graph here...
    }
```

Now the idea was that everytime I draw this I first lay out a white surface, so it removes anything drawn earlier. But it doesn't work.

I'm quite new to Graphics so please don't hesitate to comment if I'm doing it completely wrong.

Thanks in advance.

-Alex

Comment: Are you sure the correct background color is set?

Comment: I tried with g.setColor(Color.White) and g.fillRect(..) but it didn't work either sadly.

Comment: You don't need to clear the graphics every time, it is part of the double buffering process which is implemented in Swing by default.

Comment: You will do better to slightly expand this code snippet in a way that produces the problem so we can run it ourselves.

Comment: I would but if I send you more of it I would need to send almost everything for you to make it work. Anyway it seems I was able to work around the problem by manually calling repaint() on my JPanel. Thanks for your help though.